# Java dividing two floats/doubles (values retrieved from variables)

Tags: java

I have a weird division problem with floats and doubles. I want to do a variety of divisions and multiplications.

See the following code:

```java
List<Double> values = List.of(25.0, 25.0);
System.out.println(values);
// prints: [25.0, 25.0]
float totalValue = 0f;
for (Double value : values) {
    totalValue = totalValue + value.floatValue();
}

float numValues = (float) values.size();
float completeValue = totalValue / numValues;
// completeValue: 6.25, totalValue: 50.0, numValues: 2.0
float rndValue = 50f / 2f;
// rndValue: 25.0
String oneDpValue = String.format("%.1f", completeValue);
return Double.valueOf(oneDpValue);
```

I'm confused as to why `completeValue` comes back completely wrong. I've added `rndValue` just for comparison when values aren't taken from variables and it returns the correct result.

**Note:**
Values in the comments are produced by a debugger in IntelliJ. I've also attempted at simply printing `totalValue` and `numValues`. Both come back as `50.0` and `2.0`, respectively.

Could someone kindly explain why this is?

I have looked around for similar problems and tried using a suggestion (for a somewhat similar problem) to use `BigDecimal`, however, it still produced the same result.

Thanks!

Comment: Double check your data. I'm betting that it isn't what you think it is.

Comment: If `totalValue` is 50 and `numValues` is 2, then `completeValue` cannot be 6.25. Create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what you claim. I bet you cannot create such an example, because it's impossible.

Comment: The values in the comments are produced by my debugger in IntelliJ. I will double check the values and come back. I'll produce an MRE if I still can't see a solution.

Comment: Just to add - I've printed 'totalValue' and 'numValues', however both come back as 50.0 and 2.0.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that may be happening is you have a debugger running, and it's cached some of the data from a previous run, and it's using the old data for whatever reason. Restart IntelliJ / "invalidate caches" to fix that.

Comment: Make a complete, compilable running example. If there are only two double, this is pretty trivial.

Comment: Actually I did it for you here http://ideone.com/N8SoL3 it uses the same code, but I created the list.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. However, even if I update 'values' to be a List.of(25.0, 25.0) same result is given. BUT, if the same code is moved in to a new class with just 'main' method - the results are correct.

Comment: To give more context, the code lives in a static method (it's a static class) and gets executed whenever called. Even with hard-coded values for list 'values' it still returns incorrect results. This is rather concerning :/

Comment: I've added the complete code in the static function where it lives..

Answer (score -1):

First of all, thank you all for your input.

It turns out the `completeValue` was cached (even though I did reset the cache and restart my IDE). It simply took re-writing the same line and the correct result was being produced.

```java
float completeValue = totalValue.floatValue() / numValues; // completeValue: 6.25;
float completeNewValue = totalValue.floatValue() / numValues; // completeNewvalue: 25.0
```

I must say I've never seen this happen in the past, however I hope it helps someone who has a similar issue in the future.

Comment: Complete code would be code that compiles, eg a class static void main, and the static method you're calling. If you're using a debugger, add that information. There is no way to reproduce this problem, and as it stands, there is no way this will help somebody in the future. Also what ide are you using?